# How to loop through the nested JSON data in React?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am trying to map through nested JSON Data in React. The data looks like this

```
const employees = [
  {
    data: [
      {
        stuff: [
          {
            onetype: [
              { id: 1, name: "John Doe" },
              { id: 2, name: "Jane Doe" }
            ]
          },
          { othertype: [{ id: 2, company: "IKEA" }] }
        ]
      },
      {
        otherstuff: [
          {
            thing: [
              [1, 42],
              [2, 2]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to map each oneType name. Right now I am trying to do with map function but not sure whether I can do this or not. I have tried **Object.keys**, **Object.entries** but it didn't help and also tried **`{oneType.name}`** that doesn't work either. I am not sure how to reach the inner index of oneType.

Does anybody have any idea? Am I doing something wrong here or should I map the whole array of objects in a totally different way?

**Update**: I want to show listedItems of oneType.name on UI page

- John Doe
- Jane Doe

The render method looks like this:

```js
function App() {
  const employees = [
    {
      data: [
        {
          stuff: [
            {
              onetype: [
                { id: 1, name: "John Doe" },
                { id: 2, name: "Jane Doe" }
              ]
            },
            { othertype: [{ id: 2, company: "IKEA" }] }
          ]
        },
        {
          otherstuff: [
            {
              thing: [
                [1, 42],
                [2, 2]
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {employees && employees.data && employees.data.length > 0
        ? employees.data.map((item) => (
            <div>
              {employees.data[item].stuff.map((datum) => (
                <div>
                  {employees.data[item].stuff[datum].map((type) => (
                    <div>
                      {employees.data[item].stuff[datum].onetype[type].map(
                        (other) => (
                          <h1>{other.name}</h1>
                        )
                      )}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While it's possible to do what your asking with some recursion, I am hesitant to answer until it's clear what you want the data to show. It's likely there is a better schema design. Update your question to include more info on what the data should show (perhaps some example data too).

Comment: It might be better to extract all the data you want from the json first (step 1), then try to display it in the render (step 2). Right now you are doing both simultaneously: it gets confusing in a hurry and I'm not sure it's performant...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question. I am expecting to show the key values of 'oneType' names on my UI page. I hope my question is clear now. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data schema is kind of random :|, to keep the code clean I created a helper function to iterate over the keys of an object and iterate again in case it is an Array, this print the list of names and in case you needed also the company name, you can omit it by adding this expression in the condition that avoids rendering arrays

`if (Array.isArray(datumType) || !datumType.name) return null;`

```js
function renderWithKeys(item, renderFunction) {
  return Object.keys(item).map((key) => (
    <div>
      {Array.isArray(item[key])
        ? item[key].map((child) =>
            renderFunction ? renderFunction(child) : renderWithKeys(child)
          )
        : JSON.stringify(item[key])}
    </div>
  ));
}

function App() {
  const employees = [
    {
      data: [
        {
          stuff: [
            {
              onetype: [
                { id: 1, name: "John Doe" },
                { id: 2, name: "Jane Doe" }
              ]
            },
            { othertype: [{ id: 2, company: "IKEA" }] }
          ]
        },
        {
          otherstuff: [
            {
              thing: [
                [1, 42],
                [2, 2]
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  const employeesData = employees[0];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {employeesData && employeesData.data && employeesData.data.length > 0
        ? employeesData.data.map((item, employeesIndex) => (
            <div key={employeesIndex}>
              {renderWithKeys(item, (datum) =>
                renderWithKeys(datum, (datumType) => {
                  if (Array.isArray(datumType)) return null;
                  return <h1>{datumType.name || datumType.company}</h1>;
                })
              )}
            </div>
          ))
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In case you only need to access those names and you're using lodash, it can be simplified to this code

```js
  import get from "lodash/get";
  
  ...

  const data = get(employees, "[0].data[0].stuff[0].onetype");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data && data.map((item) => <h1>{item.name}</h1>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```